# How to make a listView with changing images

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to make a list in which each row has an imageView that changes every second for example listItem 1 has an imageView that changes between 2 drawables and listItem 2 has an imageview that changes between 2 drawables that are different from listItem1. My code changes all listItems imageViews to the same drawables. How can i achieve what im trying ?

```
public class GymWorkoutList extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] name = {"Push up", "Side Plank"};
String[] sets = {"5", "4"};
String[] reps = {"12", "10"};
int[] img = {};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gym_workout_list);

    final ListAdapter gymExerListAdapter = new GymWorkoutListAdapter(this, name, reps, sets, img);
    ListView gymList2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListaExerciciosGym2);
    gymList2.setAdapter(gymExerListAdapter);

}}
```

Adapter

```
public class GymWorkoutListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public static int[] imgArray = {R.drawable.pushup1,R.drawable.pushup2};
public static int[] imgArray2 = {R.drawable.sideplank1,R.drawable.sideplank2};
int[] img={};
String[] sets={};
String[] reps={};
String[] name={};
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public GymWorkoutListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String[] name, String[] sets, String[] reps, int[] img) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_gym_workout_list_adapter,name);

    this.name=name;
    this.c=context;
    this.sets=sets;
    this.reps=reps;
    this.img=img;
}

public class views
{
    TextView nameText;
    TextView setsText;
    TextView repsText;
    ImageView imgView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    View customView = convertView;
    if(customView == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gym_workout_list_adapter, parent, false);
        customView.setMinimumHeight(parent.getHeight()/getCount());}

    final views holder = new views();
    holder.nameText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.exerText);
    holder.setsText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.numSets);
    holder.repsText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.numReps);
    holder.imgView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(imageView);


    holder.nameText.setText(name[position]);
    holder.setsText.setText(sets[position]);
    holder.repsText.setText(reps[position]);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i=0;
        public void run() {
            holder.imgView.setImageResource(imgArray[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>imgArray.length-1)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 650);
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

    Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;

        public void run() {
            holder.imgView.setImageResource(imgArray2[i]);
            i++;
            if (i > imgArray2.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 650);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable2, 1000);

    return customView;
}}
```

Custom row XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.andre.fitness.Workouts.GymWorkoutListAdapter">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pushup1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sets:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/exerText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/exerText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/exerText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reps:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numSets"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/reps"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reps"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numReps"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/numReps" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numReps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sets"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/exerText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/exerText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

define view as array in adapter constructor

```
 ...
imgView = new ImageView[adapter.size()];
```

and I recommend to reset adapter with different sort of image.
Also create custom view and handle changing background inside customView class.
if you want 2 set of views then create 2 customView extends of ImageView.
check out this tutorial for creating custom view
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

In the layout of your List item(layout of row) of the custom List view, You can keep both of your images, with visibility of one as `VISIBLE` and other as `GONE`. Now when you want to change the image, you can programmatically change the visibility of the views.

This is what I'm talking about.

Your layout of **custom row** can be look something like:

```
   <RelativeLayout>
      <ImageView
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:id="@+id/img1"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img2"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for changing visibility:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     img2.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
     img1.setVisibility(VIEW.VISABLE);
 }
```